# I am replacing a class component of react-tag to funcinate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am replacing a class component of react-tag with a function component.
The original one is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tag-input-1nelrc?file=index.js
However , Tag it does not work well...
How should I fix it?
Error says
×
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tags: [{ id: 'Thailand', text: 'Thailand' }, { id: 'India', text: 'India' }],
      suggestions: suggestions,
    };
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleAddition = this.handleAddition.bind(this);
    this.handleDrag = this.handleDrag.bind(this);
    this.handleTagClick = this.handleTagClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete(i) {
    const { tags } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      tags: tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i),
    });
  }

  handleAddition(tag) {
   this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
  }

  handleDrag(tag, currPos, newPos) {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    const newTags = tags.slice();

    newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
    newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);

    // re-render
    this.setState({ tags: newTags });
  }

  handleTagClick(index) {
    console.log('The tag at index ' + index + ' was clicked');
  }

  render() {
    const { tags, suggestions } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTags
          tags={tags}
          suggestions={suggestions}
          delimiters={delimiters}
          handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
          handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
          handleDrag={this.handleDrag}
          handleTagClick={this.handleTagClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```
const suggestionsi = COUNTRIES.map((country) => {
  return {
    id: country,
    text: country,
  };
});
const delimiters = [KeyCodes.comma, KeyCodes.enter];

const SuggestTags = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([{ id: "", text: "" }]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([{ id: "", text: "" }]);

  setTags([
    { id: "Thailand", text: "Thailand" },
    { id: "India", text: "India" },
  ]);

  const handleDelete = (i) => {
    const { tags } = this.tags;
    setTags(tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i));
  };

  const handleAddition = (tag) => {
    setTags({ tags: [...this.tags, tag] });
  };

  const handleDrag = (tag, currPos, newPos) => {
    const tags = [...this.tags];
    const newTags = tags.slice();

    newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
    newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);

    setTags(newTags);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTags
        tags={tags}
        suggestions={suggestions}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        handleAddition={handleAddition}
        handleDrag={handleDrag}
        delimiters={delimiters}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The one at the link above, works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your function component, it is currently setting state on every render.

```
  // every render
  setTags([
    { id: "Thailand", text: "Thailand" },
    { id: "India", text: "India" },
  ]);
```

Instead pass the initial tags into the `useState` initial value for tags, and only `setTags` when the data changes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was helpful.Is there any good way to load initial tags? I would like to default tags from Json...

Comment: @user14232549 take a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state